# Create multiple kml files in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python programing language. I have created the codes, based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844948/trying-to-make-a-kml-file-in-python).

I prepared two simple programs:

```
import simplekml

List2 = [ [ 'Placemark','old file', 51.500152, -0.126236 ] ] # description, lat, lon
List3 = [ [ 'New placemark','new file', 51.600152, -0.136236 ] ]

kml = simplekml.Kml()
for row in List2:
    kml.newpoint(name=row[0], description=row[1],
    coords=[(row[3], row[2])])  # lon, lat, optional height
for row in List3:
    kml.newpoint(name=row[0], description=row[1],
    coords=[(row[3], row[2])])  

kml.save("test2.kml")
```

and from another file here:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", description="Description", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])  # lon, lat,optional height
kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch2", description="<b> Botanic garden </b> in South Africa", coords= 
 [(18.532314,-33.788862)])
kml.save("output/botanicalgarden2.kml")
```

I know that this code ([`simplekml tool`](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST85PsG3XdzWxU/?hl=ms)) can be used for the bulk `.kml` data, as it was mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST85PsG3XdzWxU/?hl=ms).

Could you tell me how to write this code not repeatedly, as I did? I would like to have a multitude of place mark locations within one list/new point, when possible.

Comment: TIL that mathematical tools take `(lon, lat)`, instead of `(lat, lon)`, because it maps to the common way to put `(x, y)` coordinates for plotting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code you already have everything you need, you just don't use it. `List2` and `List3` are each lists of points to create. But they only contain one point, so your `for` loop does nothing exciting, it only runs once.

You can simply add more points to any of the lists, here I take the first as an example:

```
import simplekml

points = [['Placemark', 'old file', 51.500152, -0.126236],
          ['New placemark', 'new file', 51.600152, -0.136236]] # description, lat, lon

kml = simplekml.Kml()
for point in points:
    kml.newpoint(name=point[0], description=point[1],
                 coords=[(point[3], point[2])])  # lon, lat, optional height

kml.save("test2.kml")
```

You could make this a bit more readable by using a `collections.namedtuple` for the markers. This way your comments become superfluous:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import simplekml

Marker = namedtuple("Marker", ["name", "description", "lat", "lon"])

points = [Marker('Placemark', 'old file', 51.500152, -0.126236),
          Marker('New placemark', 'new file', 51.600152, -0.136236)]

kml = simplekml.Kml()
for point in points:
    kml.newpoint(name=point.name, description=point.description,
                 coords=[(point.lon, point.lat)])

kml.save("test2.kml")
```

Note that I followed Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), when naming my variables. Variables and functions should be `lower_case` and only classes (such as the namedtuple class I create) should be in `PascalCase`. PEP8 also recommends putting a space after commas and not to use unnecessary whitespace.